# Bokeh callbacks with CustomJS: is there a way to trigger a callback with CustomJS from inside another callback with custom JS?

Tags: javascript, python, callback, bokeh

Bokeh callbacks with CustomJS: is there a way to trigger a callback with CustomJS from inside another callback with custom JS? Additionally and related to the first question: is there a way to prevent triggering a callback when modifying the property or producing the event that triggers that callback? I have been trying to find information or a way to do this from the Bokeh docs but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `CustomJS` from `CustomJS` - yes, absolutely. `CustomJS` is an object with an `execute` method that accepts `cb_obj` and `cb_data`. Just call it like a regular method and that's it.

Setting a property without triggering callbacks - it's possible in JavaScript, but it's an implementation detail that you should not rely on. If you're interested, look up the source of the `HasProps` class in BokehJS source code, it has a `setv` method. And I don't think it's possible at all in Python.

Comment: But how do you call CustomJS in the JS code? Something like ???.execute(cb_obj,cb_data)? I cannot find any example anywhere about this. Regarding the other question, I understand it's something that shouldn't be used, but in this case I have one callback changing a specific property ('visible' for legend items) a number of times, thus triggering another callback as many times, and I would prefer to control when the second callback is triggered to avoid a slow response.

Comment: "Something like ???.execute(cb_obj,cb_data)?" - yes, exactly like that. There are no examples because BokehJS is not yet documented since it's not considered stable.

Comment: I think I'm going to try first attaching callbacks to tags, then using those tags to trigger the callbacks, as suggested in Bokeh Discourse. Using the execute method looks like a dangerous way to play with things that shouldn't be used directly.